# Linq joins throwing exception

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use left join with multiple tables 
which was working fine until one more table was in introduced (tb4) as now
it is throwing object reference not set.

Before tb4 was introduced, i get 3 records from earlier resultset which have stateId = null. 
But as I am using the same id(i.e stateid) in my last join which is coming to be null in aa ie ( aa.StateId). so, it is throwing 
exception. Can we handle this thing while applying join that if a joining key comes to be  null, how can we handle that.

```
from tb1 in this.table1  join tb2 in table2 on tb1.Id equals tb2.fkId into temptbl
from aa in temptbl.DefaultIfEmpty()
join tb3 in table3 on tb1.Id equals tb3.StudentId into studentInfo
from pp in studentInfo.DefaultIfEmpty()
join state in tb4 on aa.StateId equals state.StateId into statesTemp
from ss in statesTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new MyModel
{  
    City = aa == null ? string.Empty : aa.City + ", ",
    State = ss == null ? string.Empty : ss.State1,
    PostalCode = aa == null ? string.Empty : aa.PostalCode,
    studentid = pp.PeopleId
}).ToList()
```

Comment: its already a left join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that when left joining table `tb4` you are accessing `aa`'s `StateId` property. However `aa` itself is the result of a left join and thus might be null. Accessing its property will throw the exception.

As you are using C# 5.0 you should:

```
join state in tb4 on (aa == null ? null : aa.StateId) equals state.StateId
```

For C# 6.0 and newer you can use the`?.` null propagation operator instead.

Comment: no one is working.Its showing syntax error. Is it really used in this way? Csharp.csparser : A syntax has been discovered in the file blah blah on line 109

Comment: @Sandy - what C# are you using. The operator was introduced in C#6.0.

Comment: Apparently none of this applies to `Queryable` query since `?.` operator is not supported in expression trees. Probably you need to ask OP to clarify the question and eventually remove `entity-framework` and `linq-to-entities` tags.

Comment: Super!! I was stuck from many days.. Thanks experts But could you please explain me how it started working now. As now we have explicitly defined in conditional operator to take aa=null if it is null but actually it is already null.?

Comment: @Sandy - the difference is that now you are not accessing `aa.StateId` when `aa` is null. Just like what you already did in the `select` before.